# Options for theming in SharePoint Subscription edition

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, sharepoint-server, 2019, sharepoint-subscription

I am looking to add new declarative theme to sites hosted on SharePoint subscription server

I have [created themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview) and [used PS scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-powershell) for adding them in SharePoint online, but is it supported in Subscription edition?

```
Add-SPOTheme -Identity "Organization Branding" -Palette $themepalette -IsInverted $false -Overwrite
```

Or are we only limited to the SharePoint theming engine and use the .spcolor etc?

I am looking for best practice/recommendations for deploying a theme in Subscription edition, suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview

And: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-rest-api

You are not limited to the SharePoint theming engine and the use of `.spcolor`. You can create custom themes by creating additional color palettes, font schemes, and master pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-deploy-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint

Upload your theme to the Theme Gallery and the Master Page Gallery, you can deploy a theme to a site by using the user interface or by using code. To apply the theme, open your modern site and click on the cog icon, click on "Change the Look", select your custom theme and click Apply.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, I tried the rest api way, it seems to change the site theme and create a new theme in the _catalogs/theme  but the newly created theme is not available as an option when I click on "Change the look" in a modern page. Were you able to create an option there?